# updating wordpress with pure php but user password need to be unchanged

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, password-hash

I want to update my small website to pure PHP. But, user will try to login with their old password.

But, I can't use wordpress authentication function anymore. How, I will be able to do that?

How can I verify my users? I think, i need to figure out hashing and salting process of wordpress.
where I will be able to find that?

Comment: In wordpress all users detail store in WP_users table so you can use that table in php project and password store in database with MD5 format so you can verify users with this algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress's default hashing mechanism is MD5. And user data is stored in the table `wp_users` in db.

[image]

So, what you have to first think about is, how you are storing the passwords of your current website (non-WordPress). As you already know PHP has the built-in `md5()` function.

If you are storing it in plain text format(which is not recommended at all), then you can simply iterate through those passwords in your current db and insert them to the `wp_users` table (in your new WordPress site), passing the password to the `md5()` function.

If you were storing it in encrypted form, ie. which can be decrypted back later (not recommended), then also you would be able to iterate through the passwords, decrypt it, then insert to the `wp_users` table like the above way.

But if you were using a one-way encryption(hashing), and if it's MD5, then straight away you can insert the hashed password stored in your current db to the WordPress db and it should work!

But if not MD5, then it would be a difficult task. In that case, I would suggest inserting the user data in WordPress db and temporary random password in the `user_pass` field. And then send the user a an email with link to reset the password programmatically. WordPress has a built-in function called [get_password_reset_key()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_password_reset_key/) and you can use something like this to send it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/275269/60666